# How to deep copy an array of enum

Tags: arrays, enums, deep-copy

I have an 8*8 matrix of enum called "typArr".
I want to clone this array so if i change somthing in one of them it wont affect the other one.
I've tried to do this:

```
Type [] [] cloneType = typArr.clone();
```

the enum :

```
public enum Type {A,B,Empty,SuperA,SuperB,UnPlayed; }
```

But when I change the cloneTyp it change the typArr too.
How do I deep copy this array so they dont affect each other?

Comment: You need to clone the elements of the outer array. @close-voter I don't find anything unclear about this question.

Comment: But how do i clone the element? I know how to clone array of objects using copy cunstractor, but what do i do with Enum?